# How to force Gradle process carriage return (\r) properly?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, carriage-return, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have simple code and three different outputs. How to force IDEA and/or Gradle to process carriage return properly ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.format("%2d\r", i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

1. Intellij Idea just interprets '\r' as '\n'. And nothing can be done.
2. Command "gradle run"
   spoils output with execution time messages on each line. If "--console=plain" is set then messages go out but '\r' turns into '\n'.
3. And only plain "java MyApp.Main" works as it should.

[image]

Comment: Try sticking `System.out.flush()` after the format call

Answer (score 0):

Adding System.out.flush() fixes it. As mentioned by Zac Sweers